# Get the fundamental frequency and converting it into RPM

Tags: android, audio-recording, audio-processing

I really need help. I searched over 13 hours for this but I didn't find something helpful

I have been working on an Android project for a while that displays the fundamental frequency of an input signal ((`IN RPM`)) as a live bar . I have successfully implemented the `AudioRecord` class and am getting data from it. I performed `FFT` on this data to convert it from digital domain to frequency domain.

```
int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
                channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
        AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, frequency,
                channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);

        short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
        double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];
        try {
            audioRecord.startRecording();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e("Recording failed", e.toString());
        }
        while (started) {
            int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / 32768.0; // signed 16
                                                                // bit
            }

            transformer.ft(toTransform);
            //Here i have FFT of the input sound in toTransform[]
        }
```

Now I need to get the Fundamental frequency of this data in RPM format and display it at a live bar.

Please I really need any help, any link or any project source.

Comment: @eRuLL ... you have any answers please ? :)

Comment: no frequencies knowledge, sorry.

Comment: Why don't you try something besides FFT?  Like auto-correlation or something (if the sound is monophonic)?